# Multiple Mints, Same Collection

Tags: collections, directory, wallet

I launched a collection and it was sold out in few different batches. Since thats the case all NFTs have different 'folders' in Phantom wallet even they are all under the same collection on ME profile page. How can I group them all into one folder, so they are not divided in more groups based on when the mint date was?